# Query works in MSSQL, but not in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I have a method that receives a name of either a Group or a User (email) and has to return the Abstract_Entity object of the Group or User.

The MSSQL query seems to work in all cases, but the only time the LINQ query works is when the string is the email of a user.

TranslateUserOrGroup(string name): Abstract_Entity

*Do you guys see any difference in the MSSQL query and the LINQ code?*

**The LINQ query**

```
return (from e in complementCoinsEntities.Abstract_Entity.AsNoTracking()
     join eg in complementCoinsEntities.Entity_Group on e.ID equals eg.entityID
     join g in complementCoinsEntities.Group on eg.groupID equals g.ID
     join u in complementCoinsEntities.User on e.ID equals u.userID
     where userOrGroup == u.email || userOrGroup == g.name 
     select e).SingleOrDefault();
```

**The MSSQL query**

```
select DISTINCT ae.ID
from Abstract_Entity ae
join Entity_Group eg on ae.ID = eg.entityID
join [Group] g on eg.groupID = g.ID
join [User] u on ae.ID = u.userID
where g.name = 'test' OR u.email = 'test'
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried with | instead of || ?

Comment: Not entirely relevant question: is there a reason for not doing it like `complementCoinsEntities.Abstract_Entity.Where(x => x.Entity_Group.Group.name == userOrGroup || x.Entity_Group.Group.User.email == userOrGroup).SingleOrDefault();`?

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek Learned it this way

Comment: Have you checked (using profiler, or EF tools) what SQL is generated from your LINQ query?

Comment: @Kuzgun Yes, it has the same result. The user-side works but the group-side does not

Comment: @Jamiec Is there a build in tool for Visual Studio for that? Thanks

Comment: I usually just do something like `var result = (from x in ...)` and then `var sql = ((ObjectQuery)result).ToTraceString();`

Comment: Oh also http://www.linqpad.net/ is a good tool for debugging

Answer (score 2):

I would start by peeling away the SingleOrDefault and ToList() the results in the Immediate Window to see what query results are being returned. It's likely you're stripping away matching rows trying to use SingleOrDefault instead of DISTINCT. They do not function the same. So take away 'DISTINCT' in your SQL query and remove the SingleOrDEfault call, and assign to an object and run ToList and put a breakpoint. You should see what's different.

Specifically: SingleOrDefault may key on multiple results and you are not guaranteed to get any specific result back (including a null result).

Answer (score 0):

```
.SingleOrDefault()
```

> Returns the only element of a sequence, or a default value if the sequence is empty; this method throws an exception if there is more than one element in the sequence.

have you tried `.FirstOrDefault()` ?